# How to make a 4.8 kernel config change for I2S sound?

Tags: sound, kernel, dell, xps

Since Linux Kernel 4.8 the sound card is initialized in I2S instead of the old HDA mode. However, **in Ubuntu versions of the 4.8 kernel there is some config change that makes the sound card still initialize in HDA.** (Fedora and Arch initialize in I2S, which works great for my XPS 13 (9343) dual-booting with Windows)

*For example:*

*Ubuntu 16.10 using the 4.8 kernel -- initializes the sound card in HDA*

*Fedora 25 using the 4.8 kernel -- initializes the sound card in I2S.*

I would like to [build my own kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) and make the config changes as per [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) so that my Ubuntu kernel initializes the sound card in I2S.

How would I do this? Which config option would I need to change?

Are there still issues with I2S in Ubuntu that's preventing the switch from HDA to I2S?

Comment: I updated the answer. I thought you wanted HDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you look for is

```
CONFIG_ACPI_REV_OVERRIDE_POSSIBLE=y
```

Set the option to `n` to switch to I2S mode.

Make sure that you edit kernel config a debian way.

Run

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
```

Then say "yes" to the flavour you want to edit. When you get into "menuconfig" interface, find the option by pressing `/` and clear the field by pressing "Space" key.

Then exit the intrface by "ESC" key and save the config.

Now you can build your kernel.

Comment: so I need to change that one to `n` ?

Comment: You need to switch it to `y`.

Comment: I see it is already `y` in the Ubuntu 4.8 kernel. So I see no problem with that.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want the I2S. You need to set it to `n`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. If I want to get and build the 4.8 kernel in 16.04 do I just do `git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-yakkety.git` ? Or is there a better way to get the 4.8 kernel source?

Comment: hmm... I've gotten into the `editconfigs` interface and I've been able to find that option using the search and then I press `1` and it takes me to the option listing:   `[ ]   Allow supported ACPI revision to be overriden` But this is just empty (excluded)  and all I can do it change it to `*` (built-in). It won't accept a `N` or `Y` in there.

Comment: y or n is in the `.config` file. In that interface just clear it.

Comment: hmm.. I did exactly that and compiled and installed the kernel but it is still using `Intel-HDA` audio and I can't get any sound. I will try again a bit later.

Comment: Maybe you changed the config for a wrong flavor.

Comment: No, I did `amd64-generic`.   `cat /proc/asound/cards` gives me ` 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7218000 irq 49
 1 [broadwellrt286 ]: broadwell-rt286 - broadwell-rt286
                      broadwell-rt286`